# Table with borders in HTML and LaTeX output from Markdown source with Pandoc

Tags: html, pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

This is a sample table in Markdown for Pandoc.

```
Simple tables look like this:

  Right     Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1

Table:  Demonstration of simple table syntax.
```

It does *not* add borders unfortunately.

I might code it as an HTML table, but in this case it will not work in LaTeX.

- How can I make a table with borders working both with LaTeX and HTML output?
- If Pandoc can't do the job, is there a similar tool which is able to?

Answer (score 18):

The following CSS adds tables to your HTML output when using Pandoc:

```
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
table th {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
}


/* Add border for the last row of the table.           */
/*      (Might be of use for table footnotes, later).  */
/* tr:last-child td { border-top: 2px solid black; }   */
```

This CSS is from Marked.app. I believe it's available to download on the [support website](http://support.markedapp.com/kb/how-to-tips-and-tricks/writing-custom-css-for-marked) for the app.

You can tell Pandoc to use a custom CSS file with the `--css` flag. Something like this should work:

```
pandoc -t html                      \
       --standalone                 \
       --css=/path/to/custom.css    \
       -o /path/to/output/file.html \
        /path/to/markdown/file.md
```

Hope that helps.

**NOTE:** without `--standalone` the CSS is not included.

Comment: "it does not add": sorry it was a typo, while I would like them. Please update your answer accordingly

Comment: A note for occasional reader: it still doesn't show borders inside the table, for that one could just set `border-*` variables from `none` to, e.g., `1px`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with Pandoc. But it takes a little bit of more effort.

You have to take advantage of the following facts:

1. Pandoc can recognize *raw LaTeX* snippets embedded in Markdown **[1]**. If the target output format is LaTeX or PDF, it will pass these snippets unchanged into the target document.

   So if you know how to write a good looking table in LaTeX, embed it with your Markdown.

   For HTML output, this LaTeX table code will be ignored however. That's not a problem, because...
2. Pandoc can recogniz *raw HTML* snippets embedded in Markdown **[1]**. If the target output format is HTML, it will pass these snippets unchanged into the target document.

   So if you know how to write a good looking table in HML, embed it with your Markdown.

   For LaTeX/PDF output, this HTML table code will be ignored however. That's not a problem, because...
3. Pandoc can recognize *raw LaTeX* snippets embedded in Markdown **[1]**.... *(aaahhh!, we had that already. See no. **`1.`** above...   :)*

---

### Trick: Use `pandoc` interactively in the terminal window

Here is another trick.

If you do not know how to start with learning LaTeX, Pandoc can teach you some. Because you can use Pandoc *interactively*.

**For LaTeX output:**

It goes like this:

1. Type in the terminal: `pandoc -t latex`.
2. Hit `[RETURN]`.
3. Nothing happens.
4. Start typing a Markdown snippet into the terminal (like you would type it into a text editor). Say, you type a table.
5. When your table is ready, hit `[RETURN]` one more time to be on a newline.
6. Then hit `[CTRL]+[D]`.
7. Voila!, LaTeX code appears in the terminal window...

See here:

```
$ pandoc -t latex   [RETURN]

  Right     Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1

Table:  Demonstration of simple table syntax.

^D
```

To be very honest with you: I didn't type the Markdown table.
I cheated.
I copied it from your question and pasted it into the terminal.
The last **`[^D]`** you see is when I hit `[CTRL]+[D]`.

This is what appeared in the terminal window then:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}rlcl@{}}
\caption{Demonstration of simple table syntax.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Right & Left & Center & Default\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Right & Left & Center & Default\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
12 & 12 & 12 & 12\tabularnewline
123 & 123 & 123 & 123\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

This is the default LaTeX table code generated by LaTeX from the Markdown input.

Now you can google for some methods *(if you are **not** a LaTeX expert yet)* to pimp that code in order to make the table looking nicer. The heavy-lifting is already done. *(And if you **are** a LaTeX expert: it still is nice to not need to do the heavy-lifting yourself, isn't it?)*

**For HTML output:**

Of course you can do the very same to output the HTML code of a table as Pandoc would generate it. Look:

```
$ pandoc -t html   [RETURN]

  Right     Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1

Table:  Demonstration of simple table syntax.

^D

<table>
<caption>Demonstration of simple table syntax.</caption>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th align="right">Right</th>
<th align="left">Left</th>
<th align="center">Center</th>
<th align="left">Default</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="left">12</td>
<td align="center">12</td>
<td align="left">12</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td align="right">123</td>
<td align="left">123</td>
<td align="center">123</td>
<td align="left">123</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="right">1</td>
<td align="left">1</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td align="left">1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Isn't that nice?

---

**[1]** <sub>You may need to tell Pandoc that you want to use some of its extensions when processing the Markdown input: `pandoc --from=markdown+raw_html+raw_tex+...`, just in case it doesn't work from its default settings...)</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to somehow turn markdown into PDF (in which the markdown contains embedded HTML snippets) in one go?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: If you use Pandoc, embedded HTML is only passed through to HTML-based output formats (HTML, HTML5, EPUB, EPUB3, DZSlides, Slidy, Slideous, RevealJS,...) and ignored for LaTeX or PDF output. I am not aware of any other Markdown conversion tool which will handle your request.

Comment: `to pimp that code in order to make the table looking nicer` -- Thanks for showing interactive mode - very cool. However, regarding borders, I can't see how, inside the markdown, one can insert LaTeX snippets to set the vertical borders. It would be in the `\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}rlcl@{}}` line, right, with `\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}|r|l|c|l|@{}}` -- the LaTeX part of your answer is finally not much use without that help.