# Visible table borders after generating HTML from markdown using pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

After generating HTML from following markdown source:

```
| Implementation | Tests |<br>
|:--------------:|:-----:|<br>
| Done           | Done  |
```

valid table is generated but borders are not visible.

Is there option in markdown to set borders to "visible" ?

EDIT: scoa answer will for work, but my aim is to use only markdown for actual files and pandoc only for format transformation to put html on web server. So: markdown or pandoc, more straightforward, the better.

Comment: The answer is posted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300329/table-with-borders-in-html-and-latex-output-from-markdown-source-with-pandoc

Comment: Browsers default to show tables without borders. If you want to change that, you need to use CSS. True, you can define styles inline in the HTML, but Markdown has no knowledge of that and can't output that. You would need to use raw HTML for that. Therefore, your question is a duplicate of the previously linked question. There is no other answer.

Comment: Waylan, thats answer I was looking for. Cannot use Markdown, must use something external. Question to close.