# Why isn't my CSS formatting showing up in Pandoc HTML documents?

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

I'm writing notes in Markdown which I want to convert to HTML using Pandoc, so that they're prettier when I look back over them. I am aware that CSS styling can be applied to documents converted with Pandoc by using the `-c` option, like so:

```
pandoc "ExamPrep.md" -c style.css -o "ExamPrep.html"
```

But this just doesn't seem to be working for me. For example, `style.css` includes the styling in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300329/table-with-borders-in-html-and-latex-output-from-markdown-source-with-pandoc) to add borders to tables, but my tables in the outputted HTML have no borders.

Answer (score 8):

As noted by [this comment](https://gist.github.com/killercup/5917178#gistcomment-2607140) on a gist with CSS for lovely Pandoc HTML styling, the `--standalone` flag has to be included for CSS styling to work, i.e.,

```
pandoc --standalone "ExamPrep.md" -c style.css -o "ExamPrep.html"
```

The [Pandoc documentation for `--standalone`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--standalone) says that it:

> Produce[s] output with an appropriate header and footer (e.g. a standalone HTML, LaTeX, TEI, or RTF file, not a fragment).

Without it, the resulting HTML has no header, and hence, no way of referencing the CSS file.